# how do i use ffmpeg to pause a stream

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I met a problem,here is the code,I want to pause for a minute ,but I do not how to fix it  :

```
 ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: If stream originates from a file, just set a timer. If it is a live stream, create a big enough FIFO buffer to store all the packets and stuff all incoming packets to it. Make `av_read_frame` to process what pops out of the buffer.

Comment: how to  set a timer？

Comment: Depends on your framework... Suggest studying the `ffplay` source code if you aren't familiar with how video players work. The basic idea here is that as long as you don't call `av_read_frame` you are effectively pausing your output stream.